# pandas: filter rows of DataFrame with other condition dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe like this

```
id  f1  f2  f3  f4
1   8.327   9.905   8.133   0.785
2   3.549   0.452   7.798   5.797
3   0.011   0.238   1.291   7.593
4   0.325   0.792   4.643   4.3
5   7.093   7.312   3.641   9.88
6   2.88    7.834   5.727   6.984
7   5.554   1.649   4.018   0.623
8   2.501   2.941   9.323   0.565
9   1.032   6.961   3.905   8.116
10  9.68    7.922   7.015   7.542
11  8.096   4.344   1.153   5.244
```

I would like to filter data by other condition dataframe. I want to find out records that satisfy all the following conditions.

```
    variable    interval
1   f1  (0,4)
2   f2  [1,3]
3   f3  (5,+np.inf)
4   f4  [0,10]
```

I know I can achieve this with the following code.

```
df.query('f1>0 and f1<4 and f2>=1 and f2<=3 and f3>5 and f4>=0 and f4<=10')
# or
df.loc[df.f1.between(0,4,inclusive='neither')&df.f2.between(1,3)&df.f3.between(5,np.inf)&df.f4.between(0,10)]
```

The downside is that I need to modify the code if the conditions change. Is there a pythonic way to handle this issue?

Comment: What is the constructor for the second DataFrame? Also, you will have to modify the code somehow, whether it it the query string or the condition DataFrame. How does it make a difference?

Comment: @mozway 
The constructor is ```
pd.DataFrame([{'variable':'f1','interval':pd.Interval(0,4),closed='neither'},
    {'variable':'f2','interval':pd.Interval(1,3)},
    {'variable':'f3','interval':pd.Interval(5,np.inf),closed='left'},    {'variable':'f4','interval':pd.Interval(0,10)}]) ```I'm wondering if it's possible to create a function that filters the dataframe using a conditional dataframe inside the function and returns all the results that satisfy the condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dynamically construct a query using:

```
left_op = lambda y: '>=' if y.closed_left else '>'
right_op = lambda y: '<=' if y.closed_right else '<'
construct_query = lambda x, y: f"({x}{left_op(y)}{y.left} and {x}{right_op(y)}{y.right})"
qry = " and ".join(
    df2.apply(lambda x: construct_query(x.variable, x.interval),
        axis = 1).tolist()
)
```

where `df2` is your second dataframe with `variable` and `interval` columns.

For your example data `qry` looks like:

```
'(f1>0 and f1<4) and (f2>=1 and f2<=3) and (f3>=5 and f3<inf) and (f4>=0 and f4<=10)'
```

Now if you do `df.query(qry)` it will give:

```
   id     f1     f2     f3     f4
7   8  2.501  2.941  9.323  0.565
```